# Property is reset on COM+ object if ContextUtil.SetComplete() is called

Tags: vb.net, com+

I've got two classes deployed as COM+ components, let's say ClassA and ClassB. ClassA has some public properties. ClassB sets values for those properties and calls a method of ClassA. The method itself does not modify the value of the property.

After the call the values of the properties are reset to default values for the corresponding types. This only happens if the called method includes statement ContextUtil.SetComplete(). Once I comment out the statetment the values of the properties remain same as they were before the method call, which is what I expect.

Do I overllok some basic concept of COM+ objects and their contexts? I would expect the property value to remain the same in any case.

Here's the simplified listing for the code:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On 

Imports System.EnterpriseServices

<Transaction(TransactionOption.Required)> _
Public Class ClassA
    Inherits ServicedComponent

    Private _propertyA As String

    Public Property PropertyA() As String
        Get
            Return Me._propertyA
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            Me._propertyA = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub MethodA()
        ' Do something
        ContextUtil.SetComplete() ' If this is called the Str property is reset after return from this call
    End Sub
End Class

<Transaction(TransactionOption.Required)> _
Public Class ClassB
    Inherits ServicedComponent

    Public Sub MethodB()
        Dim a As ClassA = New ClassA()
        a.PropertyA = "A"
        a.MethodA() 
        ' After this call the value of a.PropertyA is reset to Nothing if ContextUtil.SetComplete() was called inside MethodA()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling Commit on the Transaction, IE: ContextUtil.MyTransactionVote = TransactionVote.Commit. It could be that you are making changes and then setting the Context to complete before the changes have actually been committed.

Comment: Thanks a million. Setting the done bit makes the difference. When I call ContextUtil.MyTransactionVote = TransactionVote.Commit my references are preserved so all is good.